# precision issuse with taylor series for finding cosine

Tags: c

I've created a function to compute cosine based on taylor serie ,
only to encounter a precision problem when comparing it with the standard library cosine. 
for example,computing 23 my cos gives:
-0.53283**4**
and the standard library gives:
-0.53283**3**

I've been searching the web,and trying to figure it myself but just couldn't figure what the problem is!
when increasing the treashould to be 1.0e-7,the problem is solved.
but it should work well for 1.0e-6 as well(as it worked for my friends)

would appreciate any insight,thanks ahead.

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716

double my_cos(double rad){

int i = 0;
double numer = 1, denom = 1;    
double x2, cos = 0;     

rad = fmod(fabs(rad),2*PI); 
x2 = pow(rad,2);    

do{
    cos += pow(-1,i)*(numer/denom);
    i++;
    numer *= x2;
    denom *= (2*i)*(2*i-1);
} while (numer/denom>1.0e-6);

return cos ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rounding happens when you call `printf`

This

```
printf("%f\n", my_cos(23));
printf("%f\n", cos(23));
```

will print

```
-0.532834
-0.532833
```

which seems "wrong".

But 
if you increase the number of digits print like

```
printf("%0.12f\n", my_cos(23));
printf("%0.12f\n", cos(23));
```

it will print

```
-0.532833931872
-0.532833020333
```

So you have the precision you want. It's just the printing that makes it look as if something is wrong.

Comment: Sir, I love you.(can't believe I've wasted so much time on this)